# Problem in the execution of an RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, console, rcp, equinox

Thank you for your response.
now that I set;
normally it must start execution of the RCP application that I added to the classpath.
the first class to run is Application Activator and after when he throws an exception that no longer found.
Here is the stacktrace

```
$  CallHierarchy.sh -dir ../TestWks
+ '[' 2 -gt 0 ']'
+ case $1 in
+ '[' -z ../TestWks ']'
+ CALL_HIERARCHY_WORKSPACE=../TestWks
+ shift
+ shift
+ '[' 0 -gt 0 ']'
+ [[ ../TestWks = '' ]]
+ CALL_HIERARCHY_PROJECT_NAME=HeliosProject
+ echo 'beginning call hierarchy...'
beginning call hierarchy...
++ find ./plugins/ -type f -name 'org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_*'
+ ECL_CP=./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar
++ find ./lib/ -type f -name '*'
+ ECL_CP='./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar;./lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar'
+ ECL_CP='./plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar;./lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar;./plugins/CallHierarchyPro_1.0.
0.jar'
+ /cygdrive/c/java/jdk1.5.0_12/bin/java -cp './plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.101.R34x_v20081125.jar;./lib/log4j-1.2.15.
jar;./plugins/CallHierarchyPro_1.0.0.jar' org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main -project HeliosProject -data ../TestWks -trace -debug
-consolelog
Install location:
    file:/d:/CallHierarchy/
Configuration file:
    file:/d:/CallHierarchy/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/d:/CallHierarchy/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/C:/eclipseMetier/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar
Framework classpath:
    file:/C:/eclipseMetier/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar
Debug options:
    file:/d:/CallHierarchy/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 0
Starting application: 1906
!SESSION 2011-09-02 17:31:15.879 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.5.0_12
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=fr_FR
Framework arguments:  -project HeliosProject -trace
Command-line arguments:  -project HeliosProject -data ../TestWks -trace -debug -consolelog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.847
!MESSAGE The activator fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchyproject.main.Activator for bundle CallHierarchyPro is invalid
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchyproject.main.Activator for bundle CallHiera
rchyPro is invalid
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:867)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java
:51)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchyproject.main.Activator
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
        ... 23 more
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchyproject.main.Activator
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:867)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java
:51)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.910
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in CallHierarchyPro was unable to load class fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchypro
ject.main.Application.
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:867)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java
:51)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.gouv.finances.helios.callhierarchyproject.main.Application
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:160)
        ... 16 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.957
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exis
ts:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.957
!MESSAGE Bundle update@C:/eclipseMetier/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.0.101.R34x_v20090114-1205.jar [173] was not resolve
d.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.957
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-09-02 17:31:17.957
!MESSAGE Bundle update@C:/eclipseMetier/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.0.100.v_894_R34x.jar [174] was not resolved.
+ echo 'cleanning temp directory'
cleanning temp directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Classpath entries have to be separated by `;` (you're using a space). That could be (one of) your problem(s).

Comment: Thank you for your response. now that I set; normally it must start execution of the RCP application that I added to the classpath. the first class to run is Application Activator and after when he throws an exception that no longer found.